# Update Foreignkey values using Signals in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

I have two models `Label` and `AlternateLabel`. Each `Label` can have multiple `AlternateLabel` associated with it, that is there is ForeignKey relation between them.

```py
class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True, unique=True)  
    lower_range = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    upper_range = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"
```

```py
class AlternateLabel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=False)
    label = models.ForeignKey(to=Label, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together  =('name', 'label')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"
```

When a `Label` is created one `AlternateLabel` is  also created using `post_save` signal.

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=Label)
def create_alternatelabel(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    when label is created an alternate label with name as label is also created
    """
    if created:
        AlternateLabel.objects.get_or_create(
            name = instance.name,
            label = instance
        )
```

I also want `AlternateLabel` to be updated when `Label` name is updated For which I tried this

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Label)
def save_alternatelabel(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    when label is saved an alternate label with name as label is also saved
    """
    Label.alternatelabel_set.filter(
        name=instance.name,
        label = instance
    ).first().save()
```

But, on updating the `Label` I am getting error `None type object has not method save()`, I understand this is due to the fact that, this approach is trying to find the `AlternateLable` with new `Label` instance `name` which doesn't exist. I have been trying to figure out a way to achieve this for hours. I would appreciate any suggestion or guidance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since `Label` can have more than one `AlternateLabel` associated with it, I cannot use `.update` method. Therefore I ending up using Django `pre_save` signal. When `Label` is updated, its `id` remains same. So before the new `Label` name is saved into the database, Use `instance.id` to get the original name from the database, using which you can get the fix on `AlternateLabel`. Which can then be updated.

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Label)
def save_alternatelabel(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    when label name is updated, an alternate label name is also updated.
    """
    try:# getting old label name
        old_label_name = Label.objects.get(id=instance.id).name
        
        # getting alternate_label with old label name | this will get the alternate label 
        # which has to be changed
        alternate_label = AlternateLabel.objects.get(name = old_label_name)
        
        # changing alternate_label.name to new name
        alternate_label.name = instance.name 
        alternate_label.save()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This solution is working exactly required and has no drawback to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have access to the alternates of the instance by primary keys.

Just use:

```
instance.alternatelabel_set.update(name=instance.name)
```

But instead of signals I recommend creating methods on `Label` and using them
in views and forms.
Ex:

```
class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True, unique=True)  
    lower_range = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    upper_range = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.save()
        self.alternatelabel_set.update(name=name)
```

Comment: I tried this, but this does work when there is only single alternate label. But when there are multiple alternate label associated with single label, I get integrate errror